# Monaco Editor How to load CompletionItems from server?

Tags: angular, monaco-editor

I got an angular 8 app with the fantastic monaco editor embedded for some formula editing.
it works well so far but the list of suggestions = CompletionItems needs to change dynamically.

I am using the ngx-monaco-editor module and provide my language definition in the app module:

```
MonacoEditorModule.forRoot(MyMonacoLanguageConfig)
```

which is configured similar to this:

```
const MonacoAirLanguageConfig: NgxMonacoEditorConfig = {
    onMonacoLoad: function () {
        monaco.languages.register({ id: 'myCoolLang' });
        monaco.languages.setLanguageConfiguration('myCoolLang', { ...});
        monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('myCoolLang', {
            provideCompletionItems: (model, position) => {
                return {
                    suggestions: [
                        {
                            label: 'ThisHasToBeReplaced',
                            kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
                            insertText: 'ThisHasToBeReplacedWithSomethingCool()',
                            insertTextRules: monaco.languages.CompletionItemInsertTextRule.InsertAsSnippet
                        }]
                };
            }
        });
    }
};
export default MonacoAirLanguageConfig;
```

Then I am using the monaco editor in my components

```
    <ngx-monaco-editor [options]="editorOptions" (onInit)="initLanguage($event)"></ngx-monaco-editor>
```

I could call the server in **provideCompletionItems** but I can't reference my services nor do I have the context from the component where the monaco editor is used.
I tried to change the language registration in the **onInit** event, but thats too late it seems.

I am lost. Sorry :-/ and thanks for any help.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Legitimate question that I had as well and your answer below is clever.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're looking for a language server. If I understand your question right, you'd like to get completion items from the server.

You can have a look at [monaco-languageclient](https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient), this npm package can help you connect Monaco editor with a language server. There is also a [language server example](https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient/blob/master/example/src/server.ts) written by javascript, I believe you can find any other Monaco language server written by other languages as well if your back-end server is not using Node.js. The completion logic is [here](https://github.com/TypeFox/monaco-languageclient/blob/602e7606c046036d3627b59064bbfb4b67e7d2e8/example/src/json-server.ts#L219), you can return your completion item by customizing this function:

```
protected completion(params: TextDocumentPositionParams): Thenable<CompletionList | null> {
    const document = this.documents.get(params.textDocument.uri);
    if (!document) {
        return Promise.resolve(null);
    }
    const jsonDocument = this.getJSONDocument(document);
    return this.jsonService.doComplete(document, params.position, jsonDocument);
}
```

If you're looking for an example to show how to connect Monaco editor with a language server, I have a repository [angular-monaco-languageclient](https://github.com/Louis-7/angular-monaco-languageclient). Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution/Workaround**
I document what I did to achieve asynchronously getting completion items. I am pretty sure it was not intended like this and I will update if I find a better way or get a better answer.

When the ngx module raises the onInit event with the editor instance

> `(onInit)="initEditor($event)"`

I create a model for the editor and then I call the server to get the completionItems and put them in a model property. 
When the user starts asking for completion items the **provideCompletionItems** is called and I get the completion items from the model.

```
  initEditor(editor) {
    let editorModel = editor.getModel();
    <call webserver>
      .subscribe(completionItems => editorModel['completionItems'] = completionItems);
```

and in the language setup:

```
monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('air', {
    provideCompletionItems: (model, position) => {
        return {
            suggestions: model.completionItems
        };
    });
```

Comment: Clever solution, typescript complains but nothing that can't be suppressed. May not be the intended this way but I have a document type that stays the same but completions change based on some differences and attaching the completions to the model solves it.